# Are the Iron Islands independent now?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the Game of Thrones series finale, a council is held where

> the North asks for and receives its independence.

[Another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212830/why-did-other-houses-not-demand-this) touched on the subject of why the Iron Islands didn't ask for independence as well, and the consensus there seems to be that Yara didn't have the political savvy or the clout to pull that off.

However, could an alternative interpretation be that **the question of the Iron Islands' independence was already settled**, because [Daenerys promised it to Yara in Season 6, Episode 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58-QKUV8Nl0), and this promise was honoured?

Answer (score 6):

The Iron Islands aren't independent.

Yara voted to put Bran as King of the Seven Kingdoms, thus recognizing that he would have authority over her and the Iron Islands, before Sansa declared the independence of the North. And, during the reunion of the Small Council later on the episode, Tyrion calls Bran '*King of the Six Kingdoms*', indicating that, so far, only the North decided to secede.

Comment: Note, I don't think the term "Six Kindgoms" settles the question, as the [Iron Islands wasn't one of the Seven Kindgoms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133073/under-which-kingdom-are-the-iron-islands).

Comment: If the Iron Islands had gone independent, it is doubtful that Yara would have been at that council and given a voice on the matter. Besides, the implication when Tyrion says 'Six Kingdoms' is that everyone else is still under the authority of the crown and the newly appointed King.